# how to specified id update in server side (bean) primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

my example:

```
<p:growl id="growlId"/>
<h:form id="form">
    <h:inputText id="input" value="#{messageManagedBean.message}" 
                 required="true"
                 requiredMessage="input is not null!"/>
    <p:message for="input"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Execute JSF Lifecycle - Invoke Action One" 
                     validateClient="true" 
                     action="#{messageManagedBean.doSomeAction}" 
                     update="form growlId"></p:commandButton>   
</h:form>

public String doSomeAction() {
    if (!this.message.equals("")) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("growlId", new FacesMessage("Header", "Success!"));
    }
    return "";
}
```

in this case, i check if input null, will show `requiredMessage="input is not null!"` when click `commandbutton`, but growl show this message too.
i want to specified id of growl in server side (bean), i'm to try specified  only `update="form"` :

```
<p:commandButton ...
                 action="#{messageManagedBean.doSomeAction}" 
                 update="form"></p:commandButton>
```

but, if input not null, when submit,i dont receive message of growl, 
thanks all!

Comment: I don't get you, you want to get error message in the growl when the input is null and when its not null you don't want to show it?

Comment: You don't 'assign' messages to the growl, you address other components or leave the id out and make it a global message

Comment: if its null: a message of required: `"input is not null!"`.
if its not null, when click submit, bean will do something and show message `"success!"` on growl

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, i'm using `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("growlId");`